# browser showing half progress bar even after page is fully rendered

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, web, page-load-time

what could be the reason if browser is showing progress bar (stuck at half) as if it is still trying to load something, even after the page is rendered. this is an intranet ASP.NET website. how can I find out the reason? the browser is IE8. actually this started after the browser is upgraded from IE6 to IE8. not sure if this issue has anything to do with browser upgrade. will the tools like Fiddler can help to find out what it is still trying to load? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Your question would be better suited over at http://superuser.com which caters for general software/hardware questions.

Comment: May be some javascript code still running...!!

Comment: Hope you checked on other browsers too?

Comment: may be, but how to find that out? page works fine with all the images downloaded. but browser gives an impression that it is still processing something. I would like to know what it is so I can fix it.

Comment: I haven't checked other browsers. this is an intranet site and the only browser available is IE. I think this question is programming related, because browser displaying progress means it is still executing some code, I want to fix if there is any such code that is taking long time to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if u have behavior attached to any control. It happens sometime due to behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any onload scripts that are using `document.write()` that don't call `document.close()` when they're done?  This will cause the browser to wait, expecting more...

Comment: no, there are no document.writes in the code. the page itself looks ok with all images downloaded and works fine. but the browser for some reason still shows the progress. some pages use third party controls which emit dynamic javascript, not sure if there is a bug in them.

Answer (score 0):

Could be AJAX requests.  [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) will help.